# Full Join N-N sem repetir registros

Tags: sql-server, query

Possuo duas tabelas com relação N-N:

```
           ITEM_ORC                          ITEM_COMP

|   OP  |    Item Orçado   |    |   OP  |    NF   |   Item Comprado  |
+-------+------------------+    +-------+---------+------------------+
|   1   |      Lápis       |    |   1   |   101   |   Lapis Preto    |
|   1   |      Borracha    |    |   1   |   102   |   Caderno C Dura |
|   1   |      Caderno     |    |   2   |   102   |   Regua 15cm     |
|   2   |      Régua       |    |   2   |   102   |   Lousa Verde    |
|   2   |      Lousa       |    |   2   |   103   |   Caneta BIC Az  |
```

Preciso de uma query que traga o seguinte resultado:

```
Relação Orçamento X Compras

|  OP  |   Item Orçado   |   NF    |    Item Comprado   |
+------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|  1   |     Lápis       |   101   |    Lapis Preto     |
|  1   |     Borracha    |   null  |    null            |
|  1   |     Caderno     |   102   |    Caderno C Dura  |
|  2   |     Régua       |   102   |    Regua 15cm      |
|  2   |     Lousa       |   102   |    Lousa Verde     |
|  2   |     null        |   103   |    Caneta BIC Az   |
```

Como não há relação entre os itens, não é necessário um ordem correta entre eles. Apenas gostaria da listagem por OP, ou seja, poderia ser dessa forma o resultado, por exemplo:

```
|  OP  |   Item Orçado   |   NF    |    Item Comprado   |
+------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|  1   |     Lápis       |   102   |    Caderno C Dura  |
|  1   |     Borracha    |   null  |    null            |
|  1   |     Caderno     |   101   |    Lapis Preto     |
|  2   |     Régua       |   102   |    Lousa Verde     |
|  2   |     Lousa       |   103   |    Caneta BIC Az   |
|  2   |     null        |   102   |    Regua 15cm      |
```

Até agora fiz a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
   b.OP
   ,Item Orçado
   ,NF
   ,Item Comprado

FROM
(SELECT
   OP
   ,Item Orçado

FROM 
   ITEM_ORC) a

full join

(SELECT
   OP
   ,NF
   ,Item Comprado

FROM
   ITEM_COMP) b

ON a.OP = b.OP
```

Mas o resultado que obtenho é que para cada item orçado me retorna cada um dos comprados:

```
|  OP  |   Item Orçado   |   NF    |    Item Comprado   |
+------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|  1   |     Lápis       |   101   |    Lapis Preto     |
|  1   |     Lápis       |   102   |    Caderno C Dura  |
|  1   |     Borracha    |   101   |    Lapis Preto     |
|  1   |     Borracha    |   102   |    Caderno C Dura  |
|  1   |     Caderno     |   101   |    Lapis Preto     |
|  1   |     Caderno     |   102   |    Caderno C Dura  |
|  2   |     Régua       |   102   |    Regua 15cm      |
|  2   |     Régua       |   102   |    Lousa Verde     |
|  2   |     Régua       |   103   |    Caneta BIC Az   |
|  2   |     Lousa       |   102   |    Regua 15cm      |
|  2   |     Lousa       |   102   |    Lousa Verde     |
|  2   |     Lousa       |   103   |    Caneta BIC Az   |
```

Apenas salientando, a única relação entre as tabelas é a OP. Os itens, apesar de  coincidências, não possuem relação.

Podem me ajudar? 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para obter o resultado esperado, o que falta é adicionar a condição `Item Orçado = Item Comprado` à cláusula `ON`:

```
SELECT
   b.OP
   ,Item Orçado
   ,NF
   ,Item Comprado

FROM
(SELECT
   OP
   ,Item Orçado

FROM 
   ITEM_ORC) a

full join

(SELECT
   OP
   ,NF
   ,Item Comprado

FROM
   ITEM_COMP) b

ON a.OP = b.OP
AND Item Orçado = Item Comprado
```

Fiz um [exemplo no SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b373d/2), ainda que usando PostgreSQL.

---

## Atualização

Conforme comentários e a edição do Autor da Pergunta, não há relação entre os itens como no exemplo acima.

Particularmente eu não recomendaria fazer uma só query para trazer as duas informações. Porém, consigo ver alguns poucos casos onde isso pode ser útil, como num relatório simples que mostra a relação entre pesquisa e compra, por exemplo.

A resposta o @bruno atende bem a questão, mas vou colocar aqui uma outra opção de query um pouco diferente:

```
SELECT ISNULL(O.OP, C.OP) OP,  Item_Orcado, NF, Item_Comprado
FROM (
        SELECT OP, Item_Orcado, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OP ORDER BY Item_Orcado) AS Linha
        FROM ITEM_ORC
    ) O
FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT OP, NF, Item_Comprado, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OP ORDER BY NF) AS Linha
        FROM ITEM_COMP
    ) C
    ON C.OP = O.OP 
    AND C.Linha = O.Linha
ORDER BY OP, ISNULL(NF, 'Z'), item_orcado
```

Note que o `ISNULL` na ordenação serve para jogar os `NULL`s para o final. Isso é interessante para relatórios.

#### [Veja o novo exemplo no SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52286/3)

Comment: Na verdade @utluiz, não posso fazer essa relação. No exemplo que criei é possível, mas no BD real não há relação entre os itens, pois na tabela de orçamento os itens são escritos à mão, enquanto no comprado são itens cadastrados no sistema. 
Desculpe-me pela falha na descrição do problema.

Comment: @CassioMilanelo Neste caso não é possível fazer isso. O que você está querendo nada mais é do que trazer duas listas distintas em uma query só. Se não dá pra fazer a relação, então recupere as duas listas do banco separadamente e exiba para o usuário em duas listas também separadas.

Comment: @CassioMilanelo, o que tens que fazer então é remodelar sua tabela de orçamento, não tem como relacionar um item se ele não tem relacionamento.

Comment: @utluiz e @KaduAmaral, ainda há a relação entre Orçamento e Compra pela `OP` (não sei se acabei não deixando claro isso). Apenas não há relação entre os itens.  Não é necessários que os itens sejam apresentados em alguma ordem específica ou com algum vínculo, apenas dentro da mesma OP. Mesmo assim não é possível?

Comment: Sim, é possivel. Tem a resposta em baixo.

Comment: @bruno O que quis dizer é que não é possível é fazer a relação entre itens de duas tabelas sem que haja alguma informação relacionando os itens. A pergunta foi editada e, como você pode notar, sua resposta só é válida após a edição.

Comment: @utluiz, não reparei que a pergunta havia sido editada. Tens toda a razão.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução possível para o teu problema passa por criar uma coluna que relacione as duas tabelas. Este exemplo cria uma pseudo relação dentro de cada OP.

```
;with pOrcado as (
   select op, [Item Orçado], row_number() over (partition by op, order by [Item Orçado]) as RN
   from ITEM_ORC
), pComprado as (
   select op, NF, [Item Comprado], row_number() over (partition by op, order by [Item Comprado]) as RN
   from ITEM_COMP    
) 
select isnull(o.op, c.op) as op, o.[Item Orçado], c.nif, c.[Item Comprado]
from pOrcado o
full outer join pComprado c
   on c.op = o.op
  and c.rn = o.rn
```

Comment: Boa resposta! Não sou muito chegado ao uso do `row_number()` por causa da sintaxe verbosa e da aplicação que muitas vezes me parece gambiarra, mas por outro lado ele possibilita soluções bastante criativas. :D

Comment: Acabei por usar outras ferramentas e fazendo duas consultas independentes, mas achei muito útil sua abordagem @bruno. Obrigado!